# jquery ui-widget-content button bug

Tags: jquery, widget

I have noticed that if you have the following

```
<div class="ui-widget-content">
   <div class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></div>
</div>
```

and make the ui a button like so

```
$('.ui-icon').button();
```

It doesn't really work as the ui-widget background messes the button icon. :(
anyone knows about this bug?

**Edited**
The problem is the `background` on the `ui-widget-content` which dispositions the background position and its background url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a work around but not very pretty

```
$.each('.ui-icon',function(i,n){
    var iconclass= $(n).attr('class');
    $(n).removeAttr('class');
    $(n).button({
        icons:{
            primary: iconclass
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the selector for "interaction states" rolls up all the background properties into one declaration, which makes it impossible for sub-selectors to override individual properties:

The original looks like this:

```
    .ui-state-default, 
        .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, 
        .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default { 
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            background: #f6f6f6 url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_f6f6f6_1x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; 
            font-weight: bold; 
            color: #0073ea; 
      }
```

Break up the background into two separate declarations and it works:

```
    .ui-state-default, 
        .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, 
        .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default { 
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            background-color: #f6f6f6; 
            background-image: url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_f6f6f6_1x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; 
            font-weight: bold; 
            color: #0073ea; 
      }
```

N.B. This has nothing to do with the fact that you made it a button()-- it happens with just the HTML/CSS bits.

Answer (score -2):

I didn't know that `<DIV>(s)` could be initialized into a button.

```
<div class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></div>
```